# inputmismatch error in scanner NextLong() -java

Tags: java

*edit*
As the title stated, I cannot get any input from anyone. It should echo the error of InputTypeMismatch or if you do numbers, then It will say nullreference error. I am looking for words to be input - strings.

Can someone correct this? This is driving me insane. I don't know where to check.

Thanks is advance :)

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
            at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Unknown Source)
            at TestFile.promptsentence(TestFile.java:54)
            at TestFile.main(TestFile.java:43)
```

Here is a example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestFile{

        public static Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

        public static void main(String[] args){
                long inpu = inp.NextLong();
                // prompts after changing data-type
                String input = Long.valueOf(inp);

                System.out.println(input);

        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem causing `InputMismatchException` is following line

```
  long inpu = inp.NextLong(); // Not compilable code line
```

Use

```
 Long inpu = inp.nextLong(); // nextLong() and Long
```

Here is complete working code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestFile{
    static Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args){

            //  long inpu = inp.NextLong();
            Long inpu = inp.nextLong();

            //  String input = Long.valueOf(inp);
            String input = String.valueOf(inpu);

            System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

> Can you state how to let me input nextString() instead of nextLong()?

For this use following in main method to get string as input.

```
   String xx = inp.nextLine();
   System.out.println(xx);
```

You should definitely take a look at Following link about Scanner class with its associated methods.

[1. Class Scanner API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: This returns a String of numbers. I actually want letters to be input.

Comment: Do you mean you want to input like `qwerty`? I answered the question about `InputMismatchException`

Comment: yeah. I didn't mention it.

Comment: If you don't mention it then how do you expect us to answer it. However please state your question clearly.

Comment: Can you state how to let me input nextString() instead of nextLong()?

Comment: @user2262111 Updated the answer. I hope this will solve you issue.

Comment: Well thanks! Works. I have gave you check mark thing. Also, if you could tell me how you find all these stuff?

Comment: Actually this does not work. It says null reference. - it compiles tho

Comment: I dont understand Its supposed to work fine, You just have to replace all old lines in main method with these 2 lines. And what do you mean by --> \ _how you find all these stuff?_

Comment: I meant how do you find all this api. it's not at all organized. Do you want to talk in private and maybe me my mentor? I need help with this project and you can right my wrongs. I am creating a word game for school.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get `Long` value from `Scanner` object `Long.valueOf(inp)`. Use `Long.valueOf(inpu)` instead.

Anyway I recommend to use normal variable names. Like `scanner` for `Scanner` object.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong here. **EDIT** -- Looks like your edit fixed the first two.

```
public class TestFile(){ <---
```

should be

```
public class TestFile {
```

Second,

```
public static main( <--
```

should be

```
public static void main
```

Third

```
Long.valueOf(inp) <---
```

should be

```
String.valueOf(inpu);
```

`Long.valueOf()` -- THis method produces a Long object. If you want a String object, you should use `String.valueOf(long);`

Comment: Look at the Third item on the list.